# how to proceed object recognition using edge detection and histogram processing techniques?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, object-recognition

hello everyone i am pursuing mtech my project is object recognition to recognize specific objects such as weapons etc not allowed at airport so input will be scanned images of baggage/luggage  in matlab  for now its for static images only now i am using edge detection and histogram processing techniques.. i have gone through internet found ANN genetic algorithm and many more  but can't summarize whole scenarios each paper explain in its own way plz help me out to how to proceed with object recognition using edge detection and histogram processing techniques

Comment: OpenCV is a library which you can use. Not sure whether it interfaces with Matlab though. Here is an tutorial on how to detect faces: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/table_of_content_objdetect/table_of_content_objdetect.html#table-of-content-objdetect The techniques used (also see other examples) are probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to do object recognition with *only* the contours, use [Shape Context](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/shape/sc_digits.html).

Essentially, you will have a database of shapes apriori, where you know the label of each shape (gun, something_harmless_1, knife, something_harmless_2).  At query time, you take the contour of your object and compute the *Shape Context Distance* between your query shape and all shapes in your database.  The shape with the shortest Shape Context Distance is then deemed as the true class of your object.

Alternatively, if you wanted to use the histogram of the object, you could do a similar matching but with a different distance metric.  Instead of using the Shape Context Distance, you could store a histogram for all objects in your database and compute the [Earth Mover's Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance) between your query object and all other objects in your database.

It is possible to encode both of these distances in your final result.  You can come up with some weighting scheme between them that makes sense for you.

Comment: i have found many databases such as coil-100 etc of different objects separate databases of faces too but is there any separate database of scanned images of required for my project? or i have to collect scanned images from google images manually?

Comment: thanks  Chris but can u provide me related code or step by step procedure i will be thankful to u...